# RestSharp application error : Cannot create an instance of the abstract type or interface 'Parameter'

Tags: parameter-passing, restsharp

at RestSharp 105.0.1 version I was transferring the parameters from one procedure to other as below  part of the code

```
Parameter[] parameters = new Parameter[2];
while (true)
{
    if (FirstDate >= LastDateOfYear)
    {
         break;
    }
    parameters[0] = new Parameter{ Name = "BaslangicTarihi", 
        Value = FirstDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), 
        Type = ParameterType.GetOrPost };
    parameters[1] = new Parameter { Name = "BitisTarihi", 
        Value = LastDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), 
        Type = ParameterType.GetOrPost };
    
    try
    {
        hesaphareketleriList =  
            _hesaphareketleriDal.GetList("hesaphareketleriliste", parameters);
```

but now it's giving
"Cannot create an instance of the abstract type or interface 'Parameter' "
Error as shown image.
How can I resolve this ?

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I couldn't find any sample about this

Comment: The `Parameter` record is abstract as the compiler tells you. You have not explained what you are trying to do, so it's hard to figure out an answer. I can recommend you to read the RestSharp documentation about using request parameters.